# Highcharts stacked bar chart comes empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to put a chart similar to this one here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/

When the page loads, the chart comes empty. I tried the solution here:
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2091
by adding the code part to plotOptions:

```
column: {
    borderWidth: 0
}
```

I also tried:

```
barChart = new Highcharts.Chart(barOptions);
barChart.series[0].hide();
barChart.series[0].show();
```

None of these solved it. I set chart type to column, everything is ok, then I change it to bar and it stops working. Any workarounds?

Comment: Well.. Where is YOUR code? Stacked bar charts work. We need to see your code to correct the mistake in it.

Comment: I try the exact same code here: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/a5y7v/1/, on jsfiddle, when I change it to bar, it works but not on my site.

Comment: it is probably conflicting with some other script in the file. Because, when I removed everything from the page it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was conflicting with adminLTE script file:
https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/105